# How to use the Rails 4 router to remove "www" in my domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

Currently my site loads with or without www. in the front of the domain. How can I use the Rails 4 router to redirect all www traffic to just the domain, using just the naked domain.

I was able to find existing solutions for older versions of Rails but they do not work with Rails 4: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/redirect-www-subdomain-to-your-apex-domain-using-the-rails-router/

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this in Rails vs. setting it up in your DNS?

Comment: I'm using Heroku + Google Domains and this doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: Google Domains looks like they allow this? Here's an article on [forwarding `www.` and root domains](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141), here's a more general one on [subdomain management](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6072198). If you're ever planning to use subdomains ( e.g. have a `blog.whatever.com` vs a `app.whatever.com`), this is the way you'd want to set it up.